# image_tag doesn't behave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

OK, we are ALL at a loss here. Trying to display an image with image_tag. The path is stored in a sqlite3 varchar(64) field, with quotes around it. The field is called imagepath.

On the show page...

This: <%=@invitem.imagepath%>
gives me THIS:
"/images/5585L.jpg""

This:
<%=image_tag(@invitem.imagepath) %>

gives me THIS:
5585l (note the lower case L)

This:
<%=image_tag("/images/6287L.jpg")%>
Renders the image I want.

Anybody got a clue?
Stuart

Comment: sorry, <%=image_tag("/images/5585L.jpg")%> gives me the image I want too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= image_tag("#{@invitem.imagepath}") %>
```

Comment: thanks for trying. Same result : 5585l it's the lower case L and the omission of both extension and the rest of the path that makes me think it's doing some sort of conversion. I tried a URL "http://www.itsdotnet.net/mekathysailing2.jpg" and got mekathysailing2

Comment: I just did the following test in a template file:

    `<% a = "/images/5585l.jpg" %>`
    `<%= image_tag("#{a}") %>`

When I look at the page source it shows:

    `<img alt="5585l" src="/images/5585l.jpg" />`

I don't think that you have a problem in the template. Can you do a

    `<%= raise @invitem.to_yaml %>`

in your template file and check the data you are getting?

Comment: You are my HERO Tom. I owe you a cold beer.

Comment: my data had "" around it. image_tag SUPPLYS the quotes. Duh.